# How to trigger Automation Studio in Marketing Cloud from Sales Cloud

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have created SQL Query in Automation Studio in Marketing Cloud and I have a button in an object in Sales Cloud. I would like the Automation Studio to run when the button is clicked. Is this possible to be done by any API or others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is:

1. Create a button in Sales Cloud
2. Ask the Sales Cloud Developer team to send the file to FTP after the button is clicked
3. Trigger the Automation Studio from the FTP file